# How can I get first day of the month, 10 minutes after midnight using date function(ksh)

Tags: linux, bash, ksh

Basically title.
I need to execute a script that will launch once a month without using crontab. Launching of the script is done in another script that executes every 5 minutes.

So my current solution is:

```
if [ date +%d !="01"] then
else
./script.ksh
fi
```

which would obviously meant that the script will launch every 5 minutes for entire day. Which is not what I want.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What are your reasons for not using cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get date to put out the required parts of the date.

```
[[ $( date '+%d%H%M' ) = "010010" ]] && ./script.ksh
```

Comment: Thanks this helped :)